# Only one sectioned, static UITableViewCell updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static `UITableView` with four sections, each with one cell. During the segue to the view, two API calls are made (one for each of the first two cells). Upon completion, the first two cells are updated with the information and the background color is supposed to change based on this information.

The completion handler for the API call reloads the cell in order to update the background color with:

Section 1:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Section 2:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

To update the background color on reload I'm using (`getColorForCell` is mine):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self getColorForCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

This seems to work for the first cell, but the background color of the second cell doesn't update. What might be the cause?

UPDATE - `getColorForCell` code:

```
 - (UIColor *)getColorForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UIColor *vfr = [UIColor colorWithRed:127.0f/255.0f green:233.0f/255.0f blue:205.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *mvfr = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:163.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *ifr = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0f/255.0f green:100.0f/255.0f blue:97.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *none = [UIColor colorWithRed:224.0f/255.0f green:223.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UILabel *oLabel = [cell viewWithTag:102];
    if ([oLabel.text isEqualToString: @"VFR"]) {
      return vfr;
    } else if ([oLabel.text isEqualToString:@"IFR"]) {
      return ifr;
    } else if ([oLabel.text isEqualToString:@"MVFR"]) {
      return mvfr;
    }

  return none;
}
```

UPDATE 2

Simply a problem with my `UILabel` tags. Everything else was working. Nevermind.

Comment: What's in getColorForCell

Comment: Why don't you pass the `cell` argument to your method? There is no need to go through dequeuing the cell again.

Comment: @rocky Just an if-else checking the contents of a label that's updated by the API call

Comment: @Losiowaty Changed it, that works too.

Comment: From the code you've shown so far, I can't tell if anything is wrong. Must be in getColorForCell or something else. Have you stepped through that method and made sure that the expected label is getting the expected color?

Comment: Code added. I think it might have to do with that. Can labels in separate cells have the same tag?

Comment: Do you call `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];` at any point in your code?

Comment: @andrewbuilder No. I let the cells appear with some of the information and a neutral background. The labels that'll update have a spinner. When the API returns, the labels update and the background changes with `reloadSections:`. Bad choice?